# Myers' diff: Why V[k − 1] < V[k + 1] guarantee to choose the further D-path?

Tags: algorithm, diff, cls

As the pseudo code in the paper

```
4. If k = −D or k ≠ D and V[k − 1] < V[k + 1] Then
5. x ← V[k + 1]
6. Else
7. x ← V[k − 1]+1
8. y ← x − k
```

the line 4 indicate that if k is not -D or D, than take the one which has a greater x, than find out the snake. This confused me, shouldn't I calculate both v[k-1] and v[k+1] and find out which path is further? What if I chose the one with bigger x as start point, while turns out that the our point will lead to a further path?

And what's more, according to this:

> Namely, take the further reaching of (x’,y’+1) **and** (x"+1,y") in
>   diagonal k and then follow diagonal edges until it is no longer
>   possible to do so or until the boundary of the edit graph is reached.

I think the author suggest that both (x’,y’+1) and (x"+1,y") (in this case, the v[k-1] and v[k+1]) should be calculate.

So any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the paper missed a proof, which is very simple, but I think the missing will lead to some confusion (for me), so I gives this proof here:

in page 6, line 4, the code is as below:

```
 f k = −D or k ≠ D and V[k − 1] < V[k + 1] Then
    x ← V[k + 1]
 Else
    x ← V[k − 1]+1
```

I don't think lemma2 will lead to this, the purpose of lemma2 is to proof this problem can be solved with a greedy strategy. And according to `Given the endpoints of the furthest reaching (D − 1)-paths in diagonal k+1 and k−1, say (x’,y’) and (x",y")
respectively, Lemma 2 gives a procedure for computing the endpoint of the furthest reaching D-path in diagonal k.
Namely, take the further reaching of (x’,y’+1) and (x"+1,y") in diagonal k and then follow diagonal edges until it is
no longer possible to do so or until the boundary of the edit graph is reached.` The normal way is to get both points which extends from `v[k - 1]` and `v[k + 1]` and figure out which is a further reach path. But this will lead a double-culculate. Here's proof why only check `V[k − 1] < V[k + 1]` works:

lemma4:
if `v[k - 1] < v[k + 1]`, then path followed by `v[k + 1]` with a vertical edge with a snake will be the further rearched path in diagonal k.

proof:
let's make `v[k - 1]` to `x1` and `v[k + 1]` to `x2`. so the point followed by `x1` in diagonal k is `(x1 + 1, x1 + 1 - k)`(go right), the point followed by `x2` is `(x2, x2 - k)`(go down); the y position is useless here.
then the problem changes to: `if x1 < x2, then x1 + 1 <= x2`
since `x1 < x2 -> x2 - x1 > 0`
assume that `x1 + 1 > x2`, then `x2 - x1 < 1`, so `0 < x2 - x1 < 1`. But in edit graph, the basic move is 1, the `0 < x2 - x1 < 1` will never happen, so the assumption is wrong, so `x1 + 1 <= x2`.

I'v post this and a implementation on https://github.com/psionic12/Myers-Diff-in-c-/blob/master/README.md, you are welcome to discuss.